# How can I display a view inside a view from another controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, controller

I have 2 controllers: articles and comments. For each articles I need to display comments.

Both of them work fine on their own, but how can I get the comments/index inside the controller/show without messing everything up ?

Comment: I don't think render will work on this one, I tried anyway and still nothing. I chose to just copy the comment views to article, nested the models, create some methods and it's working like a charm, each article has their own comments. Thanks for answering though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your show view you would do something like this (assuming you have a app/view/comments view folder and a _comment.html.erb inside):

```
render :partial => 'comments/comment', :collection => @articles.comments
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make each comment render as a partial. So, from your comments index page, just render partial on all of the comments.

Then, from your articles show page, render the comments partial for the comments related to that article.

Take a look at using [partials](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) in Rails.